# 'GLIBC_2.32' not found when using apt and apt-get

Tags: apt, glibc, pop-os

I'm using Pop! OS. When running any simple `apt` or `apt-get` command in the terminal, even something as simple as `apt --help`, I get an error message

```
apt: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0)
```

However, when I enter `lld --version` it tells me tat I am using GLIBC 2.32. - specifically, it says

```
lld (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.32-0ubuntu3) 2.32
```

Every fix I've found online has suggested using something like `sudo apt clean` to clean, update or otherwise fix things, but the Catch-22 here is that `apt` is precisely what I can't use. Is there some sort of manual fix I can do?

This issue is making my computer basically unusable, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What *version* of Pop!OS are you using? Are there multiple versions of apt installed on your system (check with `type -a apt` from a bash shell for example).

Comment: I'm using Pop!_OS 20.10. And, yes, you are right, I have two versions of apt installed -- one at /usr/bin/apt and one at /bin/apt

Comment: That’s normal (unless somehow `/bin/apt` and `/usr/bin/apt` are different). What does `ldd /bin/apt` output?

Comment: Agreed those are likely the same (/bin symlinked to /usr/bin) - I was thinking more along the lines of a newer source-built `apt` in /usr/local that was linking to older libs in /usr, however that does not appear to be the case here.

Comment: try `ldconf`, I had success with that in the past.

Comment: @StephenKitt When I do ```ldd /bin/apt``` I get the same ```/bin/apt: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0)``` error message.

Answer (score 0):

Download and upgrade the following packages using `sudo dpkg -i` then `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and hopefully it'll solve your problem as it did with me

```
apt_2.3.15_amd64.deb         libapt-pkg6.0_2.3.15_amd64.deb   libc-bin_2.33-6_amd64.deb
apt-utils_2.3.15_amd64.deb   libc6_2.31-13+deb11u2_amd64.deb  libc-l10n_2.33-6_all.deb
debconf_1.5.79_all.deb       libc6_2.31-13+deb11u2_i386.deb   libgcc-s1_11.2.0-16_amd64.deb
debconf-i18n_1.5.79_all.deb  libc6_2.33-6_amd64.deb       libgcc-s1_11.2.0-16_i386.deb
debconf-utils_1.5.79_all.deb     libc6_2.33-6_i386.deb        libstdc++6_11.2.0-16_amd64.deb
gcc-11-base_11.2.0-16_amd64.deb  libc6-dev_2.33-7_amd64.deb   libstdc++6_11.2.0-16_i386.deb
gcc-11-base_11.2.0-16_i386.deb   libc6-dev_2.33-7_i386.deb    locales_2.33-6_all.deb
```

As sometimes dependent packages tend to break while trying to update one or another package independently so by doing so could help solve it though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command( if your program is build with GO)

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o main main.go
```